# htaccess: redirecting site domain to subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect users accessing mysite.com to www.mysite.com in my .htaccess file.

The problem is anything I try won't work, I think because `^mysite.com` doesn't exclude `www.mysite.com` so that will create a bad loop, but I usually get error 500.

I also need to exclude another subdomain, the `img.mysite.com`.

How can I do that?

I used many examples from the net & a few htaccess generators, which gave me this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.com[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Comment: `^example.com` (please use that domain for examples) _does_ exclude `www.example.com` because it is anchored at the start with `^`... And it doesn't rewrite `img.example.com`. I'd remove the `[nc]` though (there should be a space in front of it, but it is not needed).

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This is what you need - taken from the default Drupal .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

`RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mywebsite.com$ [NC]

    RewriteRule ^/(.)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]`